# Cannot install 64 bit Microsoft Visio 2013 after uninstalling Office 2010 32 bit

Tags: installation, 64-bit, uninstall, microsoft-visio-2013

I have Windows 7 64 bit. Few days ago, I installed **32 bit** Microsoft Office and Microsoft Visio 2010.

Later, I wanted now to try Microsoft Visio 2013 **64 bit**. Hence with *Revo Uninstaller Pro* and *CCleaner* I completely removed Microsoft Office and Visio 2010 and restarted my PC.

But now every time i try installing Microsoft Visio 2013 x64, I get the message:

> We can't install the 64-bit version of Office  because we found the following 32-bit programms on your PC:
>
> ```
>   Microsoft Office Visio 2010
> ```
>
> Please uninstall all 32-bit Office programs, then retry installing 64-bit Office.

I want to install the **64 bit** version (not 32-bit) of Microsoft Visio 2013 but i don't understand why i get the message. I no longer have Microsoft Visio 2010 on my PC. Has anyone experienced the same problem, maybe there is something left in Registry ?

**UPDATE:**
I was searching all day for a solution, but here on this forum, someone mentioned something about **Microsoft Fix It**.

So I went to Microsoft Support page here : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301/de and installed **Microsoft Fix It** for Office uninstallation issue. After that I restarted my PC and now the problem is gone. Check now [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2739501/de) and [here](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall/de)

Comment: Why not re-install Office and Visio 32-bit and then uninstall them properly (you know Add/Remove Programs right?) instead of letting a 3rd party program rip and slash it out? :)

Comment: @techie007 thank you for your answer. I actually too don't like too use 3rd party programs and mess arround with the registry, but this could not be uninstalled with the Add/remove Programm. I think it is a Windows Bug, the problem has to do something with the test version of Microsoft Office 2010. But i used Microsoft Fix It and it removed some files from the registry, now i can install Visio 2013 64-Bit

Comment: @Devid - A Microsoft Fixit is a great deal safer then using `Revo Uninstaller Pro and CCleaner` futhermore its not a third-party tool its first-party.

Comment: Instead of adding solutions to the question, you can (and *should*) answer your own question, and accept your own answer if you prefer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try uninstalling Office 2010 as per this [KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301). This KB will help remove any lingering Office 2010 registry keys.